# Check if point x=0 is a point of discontinuity of second kind

Tags: functions

I have few functions and have to decide if x=0 is a point of discontinuity of second kind of function.

[image]

And I think this is right for number 1, because 1/x with one sided limit 0- is -infinity. And also number 3, because right limit(O+) of sin(1/x) does not exist. Number 2 is only jump, so it is not of second kind.

Am I right? thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right, for the first function we have
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow0^{-}}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow0^{-}}\frac{1}{x}=-\infty
$$
and this implies that this function in $x=0$ has a discontinuity of second kind.

For the third function the limit of $\sin(1/x)$ when $x\rightarrow 0^{+}$ dosen't exist and then it has a discontinuity of second kind at $x=0$.